# Is there any programming interface to use the indexing of a Java Project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, graph, dependency-graph

Like inteliij exposes apis to use the PsiTree structure generated by intellij, is there anything like this in eclipse? 
My main goal is to generate a dependency graph of a Java Project.

Comment: Possibly you want the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)